# Невыполнявшиеся / не выполнявшиеся

Tags: орфография, грамматика, частица-не

Как написать слово с -не-: "вообще невыполнявшиеся работы"?

Answer (score 1):

В принципе допустимо и слитное и раздельное написание - с разным смыслом.
Вообще не выполнявшиеся - даже не начали выполнять.
Воообще невыполнявшиеся - все невыполнявшиеся работы, а не какая-то конкретная.
Ну и ещё несколько вариантов смысла можно вложить. Нужен контекст.
Если его нет, я бы предпочел раздельное написание, оно с "вообще" выглядит более нейтральным.

Answer (score 0):

У причастия есть зависимое слово "вообще", поэтому пишем раздельно.

Answer (score 0):

читаемый - настоящее время, читающий - настоящее, читанный - прошедшее,  читавший - прошедшее время.